# sql database design for multiple restaurants

Tags: sql, database-design

I'm storing all orders from multiple restaurants.(not a chain) These restaurants have unique items which may or may not be in the same category(sweet, salty, drinks, entrees, appetizers, etc) which can then have sub categories as well(sweet->parfait, crepe; drinks->hot, cold, alcohol, etc)

For each order, there may be more than one item, with customizations(removals or additions), and with special notes not part of the customization. Serializing the data into a json string would be an easy option, but it would be really hard to search through and organize this valuable data.

Each item is comprised of parts which may or may not be common with other items in its category. The item has parts for every possible combination. All default parts are opt-out-able.

Let's start with an example. Category, subcategory, common options, item name, unique item options. Not all levels will be used always.

Restaurant A

- sweet

  - ice cream

    - # scoops (if > 1, multiple flavors possible)
    - vanilla
    - chocolate
    - mango
  - frozen yogurt

    - variation 1

      - a (default)
      - b (default)
      - c
      - d
      - e
    - variation 2

      - a
      - b (default)
      - c
      - d (default)
      - e
    - variation 3

      - a (default)
      - b (default)
      - c
      - d
      - e (default)
- savory

  - pizza

    - hawaiian

      - pineapple (default)
      - cheese (default)
      - ham (default)
      - tomato sauce (default)
      - bacon
      - mushrooms
      - pepperoni
    - create your own

      - pineapple
      - cheese
      - ham
      - tomato sauce
      - bacon
      - mushrooms
      - pepperoni
- drinks

  - hot

    - coffee
    - latte
    - cappucino
    - tea
  - cold

    - coke
    - bottle water
    - ice coffee/tea variations

Restaurant B

- sweet

  - item x
  - item y
  - item z
- savory

  - item w
  - item q
- item r

Restaurant C

- item o
- item p
- item g
- item s

If I go to restaurant a, and order a double scoop of vanilla and chocolate, 2 frozen yogurt variation 1, 1 frozen yogurt variation 2 with no b, and a hawaiian pizza with mushrooms, how would I store this order? Or is using sql the wrong idea and I should use a document store (nosql) system? Ideally I don't want to store (default) parts as part of the customizations; only things that are different are interesting.

Answer (score 2):

**Learn information modeling and the relational model.**

A straightforward information model for you application is the best start. (Actually, to any programming problem.) And you probably actually should use a relational DBMS.

You need to learn about information modeling (IM). Also the relational model (RM) and (sort-of-)relational database management systems (RDBMSs). IM gets precise where it uses the RM. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004994/canonical-text-on-database-design/24007275#24007275) answer. Especially its first link. Also see my answers to modeling questions.

The RM allows generic loop-free/declarative (logic notation) querying and manipulation with automatic implementation with certain performance with certain optimizations. Any other data structure or language should be used only because of engineering tradeoffs for particular queries and performance. This is so for *every* computing task. (The precise specification of any program can be written in logic notation.)

You can stop now. But the RM way of thinking follows.

**Find application relationship statements.**

The basic idea is you find statements to describe an application situation.

```
I go to restaurant a, and order
    a double scoop of vanilla and chocolate,
    2 frozen yogurt variation 1, 1 frozen yogurt variation 2 with no b, and
    a hawaiian pizza with mushrooms
```

Make fill-in-the-blanks versions.

```
    person [p] at restaurant [r] has some pending order o
AND o includes item some item i
AND item i is an ice cream
AND item i has [n] scoops of flavour [f]
...
AND order o includes some item j
AND item j is a pizza
AND item j base is hawaiian
AND item j has extra [mushrooms]
```

**Find basic statements.**

```
person [p] at restaurant [r] has pending order [o]
order [o] includes item an item i
item [i] is an ice cream
item has [n] scoops of flavour [f]
...
item [j] is a pizza
item [i] has base [b]
base [b] has topping [t]
item [i] has extra topping [t]
item [i] has topping [t]
```

**A base table has a statement.**

Each basic statement gets a base table. A base table declaration looks like shorthand for its statement & vice versa.

```
order(p,r,o) -- person [p] at restaurant [r] has pending order [o]
base(b,t) -- base [b] has topping [t]
topping(i,t) -- item [i] has topping [t]
```

A base table holds the rows that make it true. Eg in the following situation

```
    person No_name at restaurant a placed order 12345
AND person philipxy at restaurant a placed order 22222
AND person philipxy at restaurant b placed order 33333
AND for all other (p,r,o) NOT order(p,r,o)
```

the base table

```
order(p,r,o) -- person [p] at restaurant [r] has pending order [o]
```

has as value the table

```
+----------------------+
| p        | r | o     |
+======================+
| No_name  | a | 12345 |
+----------------------+
| philipxy | a | 22222 |
+----------------------+
| philipxy | b | 33333 |
+----------------------+
```

The RM way to find the best basic statements and tables is normalization (to 5NF).

**Every table has a statement**

Every statement made up of other statements has a table. Every table holds the rows that make its statement true. The statement is combined from logic operators and the table is combined/calculated from corresponding table operators.

Eg rows where

```
there's some restaurant r, order o and item i where:
    person [p] at restaurant [r] has pending order [o]
AND order [o] includes item [i]
AND item [i] has [n] scoops of flavour [f]
AND [p]=No_name AND [r]=a
```

or using shorthands rows where

```
EXISTS r,o,i: order(p,r,o) AND item(o,i) AND cone(i,n,f) AND p=No_name AND r=a
```

ie the rows in

```
SELECT p,n,f
FROM order JOIN item JOIN cone
WHERE order.o=item.o AND item.i=cone.i
AND order.p=No_name AND r=a

+--------------------------+
| p        | n | f         |
+==========================+
| No_name  | 1 | vanilla   |
+--------------------------+
| No_name  | 1 | chocolate |
+--------------------------+
```

Start with the statements. Ie application relationships. Ie relations. Hence *relational* model.

**Alas.**

Probably all the modeling advice you get will talk about "an" "m:n" "association" [application relationship] without asking *which one*. Ie *which statement*. (Beware they will use "relationship" in a non-everyday non-RM way.)

Entity-Relationship Modeling (ERM) and Object-Relational Mapping/Modeling (ORM) misunderstand the RM. They muddle the above. But you can convert from the above into their notions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to attempt a comment on SQL vs NoSQL save to say that this type of app is probably a bread-and-butter application of SQL; and the final architecture depends on how you intend to use the data.

I'd say there is a separation of concerns here between how you store and how you present the data. For e.g. a Hawaiian with extra mushrooms, what you want to present to the kitchen is (may be) 'Hawaiian + extra mushrooms'. What may be best to store is 'Pizza with Pineapple, cheese, ham, tomato sauce, mushrooms'.

I would think you want to store, by Restaurant and also by time (tastes change, recipes change) various standard combinations: From Time T1 to T2 Rest A offered a pizza called a Hawaiian containing..... This data has a different use (printing menus, quick recognition by the Chef) than recording what is actually ordered (resupply analysis, cost analysis, customer analysis, whatever else you want to do).

However, all this depends on your use cases (and even if you were too share them I probably don't have the time to read them and think about them - that's your job!). As long as whatever structure you come up with supports the use cases, then you're OK.